# Link alert ok button to a url

Tags: javascript, alert

so I got this code, which shows an alert, but now I want to link it to a url. So if a user clicks on "OK" then he/she will be taken to a url....

Here's the code:

```
 <script>

 setInterval(function(){ alert("Man! you are too slow!!!")}, 3000); //so here I need to add a url link for "OK" button...  

</script>
```

I would be grateful if you helped me with this... Aloha_mate.

Comment: I hope you have added onClick event for your "OK" button first.
I don't see any need of setInterval here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with `alert`, but you can do that with `confirm`

```
setInterval(function() {
    if (confirm("Man! you are too slow!!!")) {
        window.location.href = "url";
    }
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code for you...

```
<div id="OK" style="display:block;border:solid 1px;">OK</div>
<script>
    $('#OK').click(function (e) {
        if (confirm("Man! you are too slow!!!")) 
        {
            window.location.href = "url";
        }
    });
</script>
```